# Word 2007 VBA cannot control Pictures?

Tags: vba, office-2007, ms-word

Try recording a macro in Word 2007, notice you can't do a thing to pictures. *(Or is this a local issue with my machine?)*

And I can't even find the Picture / Image object within the Word Object Ref.

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Word, images are internally handles as shapes. There are basically two types: `InlineShapes`, which are aligned inline with the text, and `Shapes` which are all shapes floating on a page.

You can access an image depending on its type either via

```
With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
    .Width = 300
    .Height = 200
End With
```

or

```
With ActiveDocuments.Shapes(1)
    .Width = 300
    .Height = 200
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

When recording you can't use your mouse to select anything so you have to use you keyboard to select the picture and then use the menu options to manipulate it.